# file_get_content and file_put_content to include php code?

Tags: php, html

I have read a few posts on similar issues but not managed to find myself an answer.

I have a template.php file and what I want to do with it is make an identical copy (this includes any php code in that file) make a few changes and save it as a seperate page.

heres what I have so far:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("template.php");
$data = str_replace("blogpostidhere", $postid, $data);
file_put_contents($postid.".php", $data);
?>
```

The file i need gets created but it doesnt contain anything from between the php tags. It is pure html. Is there a way around this as my template.php is set to simply be copied and a single variable (blogpostidhere) to be added to make the page work. it needs php though?

Comment: you have posted not the code you actually run

Comment: Instead of having two nearly identical files, why don't you have one file with parameters

Comment: have you tried echoing $data before str_replace to make sure it is pulling it in correctly?

Comment: Works fine for me from the command line. I wonder if this has to do with `allow_url_fopen`.

Comment: The code is on a page where I can post a kind of blog for a website. Once posted I want it to create its own page and the content will be located in mysql database.

Comment: echoing the data will appear to show the page correctly but items on the page that will change over time will remain static as the php aspects have not been included.

Comment: Basically can someone please tell me how to make file_get_contents include any php code as it is?

Comment: Fixed - My own fault - problem with the URL - Thanks for the help